# Issues with using an intersect(replace(join())) sub

Tags: vba

I'm having some problem with the following code.

`rng` is a range that represents quite a large table. E.g. `A1:G600`. `refArr` is a list of row numbers. I need the following code to pass back a range so that just the rows from `refArr` can be selected out of `rng`.

However, when my `refArr` is too long (i.e. when it has over 54 items exactly) it gives me an error.... Any ideas why this would be the case?

```
Function RangeSelector(rng As Range, refArr As Variant) As Range
    Set RangeSelector = Intersect(rng, rng.Range("A" & Replace(Join(refArr, ","), ",", ",A")).EntireRow.Offset(1))
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the maximum string length for `Range` is 255.  We can get around that by using `Union`.

Notice that `Range.address` will only return 255 characters even if the actual address is much longer

[image]

In the test I use `RangeSelector` to select every other row from 1 to 600

[image]

---

### Test

```
Sub TestRangeSelector()
    Const MAXROWS As Long = 300
    Dim refArr(1 To MAXROWS), x As Long
    Dim Target As Range

    For x = 1 To MAXROWS
        refArr(x) = x * 2
    Next
    Set Target = RangeSelector(Range("A1:G600"), refArr)
    Target.Select
    Debug.Print "Absolute Address: "; Len(Target.Address), Target.Address
    Debug.Print "Relative Address: "; Len(Target.Address(False, False)), Target.Address(False, False)

End Sub
```

---

### RangeSelector

```
Function RangeSelector(rng As Range, refArr) As Range
    Dim s As String, Target As Range, v As Variant, x As Long

    For x = LBound(refArr) To UBound(refArr)
        s = s & refArr(x) & ":" & refArr(x) & ","

        If x = UBound(refArr) Or Len(s) >= 251 Then
            s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
            If Target Is Nothing Then
                Set Target = rng.Range(s)
            Else
                Set Target = Union(Target, rng.Range(s))
            End If
            s = ""
        End If
    Next
    Set RangeSelector = Intersect(rng, Target)
End Function
```

Comment: Great! one of these areas where the experimentation learning approach falls behind the study approach! I never would have found that.... thank you

Comment: @user3465779 I didn't know it either 5 months and 700 Answers ago ...lol. Thanks for accepting my answer.